# Informatica - Access Unix server from Windows client

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica, What are the different ways to connect Unix server from Informatica Windows client?

Answer (score 0):

If informatica server is sitting on Unix, you can create a command task with the following:

set >/tmp/informatica.task.out

And then check the output in your Unix file.

Also, you can run an ssh command from that machine to reach additional servers.

This is just a couple of thoughts from the top of the head.